# How to ignore if array(0) is null php

Tags: php

How to ignore if array(0) is null php

When i am print the value the array is like this: Array ( [0] => )

if i print count($testArray) it is showing 1

But if the array value is comes like this i don't want to insert it into the database.
Please suggest how can i do this.

Update:

var_dump result: array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: empty($testArray[0]) should return true, then you can skip, otherwise (if $testArray[0] has any kind of value other than null-values) it returns false.

Comment: var_dump result: array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this

```
 array_filter($testArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($testArray[0]))
    // do something
```

OR

```
foreach ($testArray as $value)
{
    if (!empty($value))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help you filter the array

```
    $array1 = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5,"f"=>"","i"=>0);
    function filter($var)
    {
        return !empty($var);
    }
    var_dump(array_filter($array1, "filter"));
```

Output

```
    array
      'a' => int 1
      'b' => int 2
      'c' => int 3
      'd' => int 4
      'e' => int 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if(!isset($testArray[0]))
{
    //here the zero key has null value
}
```

or

```
if($testArray[0] == NULL)
{
    //here the zero key has null value
}
```

But try first:

```
var_dump($testArray);
```

And let us know what it's shown.

Comment: var_dump result: array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Then the array value is not null, it's an empty string.
Try:
if($testArray[0] == '')

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to ignore an empty value but some of the codes didn't work. So I tried this and works, maybe this code will help someone out there.

```
if (empty($YourValue)){ continue; } else { echo $YourValue; }
```

> The code `continue` skips your empty value.
>
> It helps me creating a navbar inside `<li> ... </li>` code for some reason.